# Calculcating probabilities in a gaussian distribution

Tags: python, scipy, gaussian

For a school project, I have to calculate the probabilities of P(Y=2), P(Y=3), and P(Y=4) based on:

`Y = stats.norm(loc=3.0, scale = 2.0)`

My approach was:

`p2 = Y.pdf(2) p3 = Y.pdf(3) p4 = Y.pdf(4)`

However, this was marked wrong by the grading system. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you provide the exact wording of the question? Does it mention _cumulative_ probability?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is in understanding mathematics. `stats.norm` is a continuous distribution. So the probability that `Y` is a single value is zero.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html